# Проблема при загрузке отчета с формы ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#

когда я пытаюсь загрузить отчет из формы
система выдает мне ошибку "DataSet не поддерживает System.Nullable <>."
в этой части кода "rd.SetDataSource(db.equipment.ToList());"

```
    public ActionResult exportReport()
    {
        ReportDocument rd = new ReportDocument();
        rd.Load(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Reports"), "CrystalReport1.rpt"));
        rd.SetDataSource(db.equipment.ToList());



        Response.Buffer = false;
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.ClearHeaders();

        try
        {
            Stream stream = rd.ExportToStream(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat);
            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            return File(stream, "application/pdf", "Equipment_list.pdf");
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Проверьте что возвращает `db.equipment.ToList()`, возможно там действительно `null`

Comment: Инициализация db где происходит? покажите весь код который задействован в методе

Comment: Заработало, но работает только в том случае, если в программе есть всего одна таблица.
Если в диаграмме уже несколько связанных таблиц, то опять вылетает эта ошибка.